# how to install an offline .deb program with its dependencies in local repo if they don't exist

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, ubuntu-20.04

this is my [bash script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54239534/8747573) (there are others similars [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10439058/8747573) and [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65647357/8747573)):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
pkgs='main-program dependency1 dependence2'
if ! dpkg -s $pkgs >/dev/null 2>&1; then
  wget main-program.deb && apt -y install ./main-program.deb
  wget dependency1.deb && apt -y install ./dependency1.deb
  wget dependency2.deb && apt -y install ./dependency2.deb
fi
```

**question**: How can I fix my script, to install the main `.deb` program, and when I need its dependencies, if not installed, look for them in a local repository (for ubuntu 20.04)?

*Note: most of the main program dependencies `.deb` are no longer in the official ubuntu 20.04 repositories, therefore it cannot be installed with `apt-get install package` (only with `apt-get install ./package.deb` or `dpkg -i package.deb`)*

**Update:**

[This solution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/366886/266428) supposedly solves the problem of offline installation. That is, the main program looks for dependencies it needs in `/var/cache/apt/archives/` folder and not on internet

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
pkgs='main-program'
path_deb="/var/cache/apt/archives/"
if ! dpkg -s $pkgs >/dev/null 2>&1; then
  cat dependencies.txt | xargs -n 1 -P 2 wget -q -nc -P $path_deb
  dpkg -i $path_deb/main-program.deb
  apt-get install -f
fi
```

I tried it also with:

```
dpkg --force-depends -i /var/cache/apt/archives/main-program.deb
```

content of `dependencies.txt`

```
https://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/example/dependency1.deb
https://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/example/dependency2.deb
https://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/example/main-program.deb
```

but it fails:

```
Unpacking main-program ...
dpkg: dependency issues prevent main-program configuration:
  main-program depends on dependency1; However:
   The `dependency1' package is not installed.
  main-program depends on dependency2; However:
   The `dependency2' package is not installed.
Errors were encountered while processing:
  main-program
Reading package list ... Done
Creating dependency tree
Reading status information ... Done
Fixing dependencies ... done
The following packages WILL be REMOVED:
   main-program
0 updated, 0 new will be installed, 1 to remove, and 0 not updated.
1 not fully installed or removed.
672 kB will be released after this operation.
do you wish to continue? [Y / n]
```

Comment: dpkg is doing the install sequence automatically : `cd folder-with package.deb-and-dependencies/ && sudo dpkg -i *`

Comment: Thanks for your proposal, but I had already tried that option and it doesn't work, because the main program decides when to install a dependency and in what order it needs it. And that is precisely my question

Comment: `apt` priority and other configurations https://wiki.debian.org/AptConfiguration → → "Always prefer packages from a repository".

Comment: you are right, but I am not using `apt` in my script to install the program or its dependencies (only at the end to check if any dependencies are missing) but `dpkg` over the `.deb` directly. If you have the answer to my question, I would be very grateful if you post it, so that others can comment and rate